# Discord.Js give all members a role

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to make a command that gives role to all the members
Example: !give
This command should give everyone in the server a specific role

this is my code so far -

```
const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("Role-ID");
            
const Roled = message.guild.roles.cache.get("Role-ID")
            
Role.members.forEach((member, i) => { 
  setTimeout(() => {
    member.roles.add(Roled); // Adding the Role.
  }, i * 1000);
});
```

When I tested this code, it just added for me and my bot the role, and not to every member as it should do.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

By using `Role.members.forEach` you're only getting the members that currently have that role.

If you want to add a role to all the members in a guild you need to use `message.guild.members.cache.forEach`

First you find the role that you want to assign:

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("Role-ID");
```

Then you create a loop that assigns the role for each member in the guild:

```
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {

// Check if user has a higher role than the bot
if((member.roles.highest.position > message.guild.me.roles.highest.position)) {
      return;
}

try{ member.roles.add(role)
} catch(error){console.log(error}
```

Comment: Still not working
It's giving me and the bot the role, and not the others.

Comment: Please make sure that your bot's role is above the role that you're trying to assign.
In your server's settings, go to Roles and drag your bot's role to the very top.

Comment: Yea, Already did it.
But still it says "missing permissions"

Comment: Another thing you can try is going to https://discord.com/developers/applications
and select your application. Then, in the left side of the screen go to the "Bot" section and enable the "SERVER MEMBER INTENT".
Image for reference: https://i.imgur.com/dRrGaFd.jpg

Comment: Hey. did this work or are you still experiencing the issue?

Comment: Hey. No it is not working
I tried what u said, but still it doesnt give every member the role.